# I can't sort messgaes by "From"

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have 2 e-mail addresses, and in one, there is no way to view messages by "From".  There's "Received," "Size," "Categories," etc., but no "From."  ow do I add this?

Comment: What's your Outlook version?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-move-a-column-64c0627d-4f71-4590-b27b-0c4b33a67595

Answer (score 1):

[Follow this guide](http://www.officetooltips.com/outlook/tips/adding_and_removing_columns.html) to add missing cvolumns.

Essentially:

- Right click an existing field in outlook (subject, size etc headers)
- select "field chooser"
- Drag the "From" field into the main email window header bar from the field chooser popup
- close the field chooser popup
- sort your email

if you want to remove any fields, you can re-open field chooser and drag the fields from your mail window back to the field chooser